# javascript splice method and return confusion

Tags: javascript, return, splice

So I was trying to create a javascript function to *remove `n` elements* from the beginning of an array, the following is the code:

```js
function slasher(arr, howMany) {
  arr.splice(0, howMany);
  return arr;
}

slasher([1, 2, 3], 2);
```

Question:
Can someone explain to me why when I change the code inside the function to one line: `return arr.splice(0, howMany);`, the function would give me `[1, 2]` instead of `[3]`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) of splice

Returns

> **An array containing the deleted elements**. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

So you are actually getting the deleted elements array rather than the actual array.

Answer (score 1):

Its because `splice` returns the elements removed but not the array with element removed.

```
var arr =[1,2,3]
var elementsRemoved = arr.splice(0,2);

elementsRemoved = [1,2] and arr would be [3].
```

Answer (score 0):

Because splice() returns value and in the same time changes your array.

So when you `return arr.splice()` - you are returning what's returning this function, but when you `return arr` - you are returning your new array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function slasher (arr, howMany){
  return arr.splice(howMany, arr.length)
}

console.log(slasher([0,1,2,3,4],2))
```

splice syntax is splice(index, number of elemnets to be removed from that index)

or

```
function slasher (arr, howMany){
  return arr.slice(howMany, arr.length)
}

console.log(slasher([0,1,2,3,4],3))
```